# How to set word add-in width when it start?

Tags: office-js

Can you set the default width of a Word Add-in?

The default width is 323px (Windows 10). Can we make it wider, such as 360px?

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the default width of Office Add-ins. The defaults also differ by platform (Windows, Mac, iPad, Web, etc.). On Office Desktop versions the user can manually resize the taskpane by dragging it with the mouse but on other platforms it is a fixed width.

From a UX/Design perspective, Add-ins should be responsive to widths from 300px on up. This ensures users receive the full experience regardless of the platform that happen to be using at the time.

You can find detailed design guidance, templates and UI frameworks in the [Documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-design).